# What does it mean to dissolve a puzzle?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Quoted from On 'The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences' by Sorin Bangu,

> My conclusion, however, is the same-that Wigner's riddle can be (dis)solved.

I am well versed in solving puzzles but what does dissolving a puzzle actually mean?

Comment: It must be a pun based on some aspect of 'Wigner's riddle', whatever that is. PS I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend), but I'm not much the wiser!